# How to implement SSR for single vue component inside of laravel application?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm working on an laravel project. There're a lot of vue components and I need to make SSR due to SEO. I can't use nuxt.js or something like it because of my app is not SPA. I have default mix settings:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css');
mix.disableSuccessNotifications();
```

I put the vue components to laravel views (blade templates) like `<example-component></example-component>`. How may I implement SSR for there components only in this case?

I need to add this components as rendered html to the response, not as `<example-component></example-component>` due to SEO.

Comment: what is mean by SSR?

Comment: @arun server-side rendering

Comment: You may not need to do SSR for SEO. It could be enough to only render the necessary information for SEO. Google does not consider this as cloaking.

Comment: @RaduDiță before asking a question here, I asked about it on webmasters.stackoverflow: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121490/ check it out, I guess I need to do SSR here

Comment: This is a great resource https://sebastiandedeyne.com/server-side-rendering-javascript-from-php/

Comment: I think i saw a webworker based solution for this, but cant remember when or where

Comment: @DerekPollard yes, checked it out, but there's no SSR for single components, this solution based on replace of root div

Answer (score 3):

Server side rendering is not a one liner, but there are a package for laravel to do it, please check it out:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering

Answer (score 0):

The current solutions require the use of Node, or in extreme cases PHP in combination with V8Js engine.

See https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#integrating-with-a-server to get you started. `vue-server-renderer` is based on a Node/express.js implementation that renders your HTML beforehand.

I have not yet tried any solution that is PHP based and unfortunately this is the best answer I can give to you at the moment.

Comment: I wouldn't consider a PHP renderer an "extreme case" - you gain the familiarity and separation of having SSR done with something you're comfortable with. That's why there are packages from RoR and Laravel that are so popular

Answer (score -3):

Use only blade. Don't use components of Vue. You can use them for unecessary things of Clawer, Search Engine like Forms, Payment, Bookings, Carts, Check Out,