# Server side rendering or pre-rendering in Laravel and Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, seo

I have a web application in `Laravel 7` and `Vuejs2` which have some pages like home, about, cities and help. these page need to be crawled by search engines.
I have tried both ways, `prerendering` and `server side rendering` without success.

for `pre-render` there is only one package `prerender-spa-plugin` which is very old and not updated since 5 years.

`server-side-rendering` is also difficult because my web app is already designed and is going to production, it is hard to implement that now, and also not recommended to implement `server-side-rendering` because of 5 pages.

any suggestion are appreciated to make these 5 pages crawelable by search engine.

update:
my application contain other pages and components which do not need to be SE optimized, pages like user account and profiles.

Comment: @Radu Diță  I see your comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100614/how-to-implement-ssr-for-single-vue-component-inside-of-laravel-application

Comment: You could give Nuxt a try IMO.

Comment: @kissu I could use Nuxt at the very beginning of my project, now It's to hard to implement.

Comment: Moving from Vue to Nuxt could take a matter of a few minutes if you only have 5 pages. At the end, it's mainly a wrapper and you don't need to use everything in it to still get the benefits of it.

Comment: @kissu   I have 5 pages only need to be crawled by searching, the whole application has lots of pages and components. there are 6 types of user access.

Comment: Still nothing against a Nuxt migration. Give it a try, you will not lose that much amount of time. And it will be a nice tool for further quality SSG/SSR. More details available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075962/8816585

Comment: This is how you could exclude some pages from being SSR/SSG'ed and keep them as SPA only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472634/8816585

Comment: I should probably try Nuxtjs,

Comment: Keep us updated if you have any issues with the migration!

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I recommend the usage of Nuxt if you want something that could deliver a professional experience, on top of managing all the flexibility that you wish to have with an SSR/SSG tool.
Here is a more detailed answer regarding your currently available tools to achieve some SEO-crawlabale content: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69075962/8816585

You mentioned that you wished to keep some pages as SPA-only, this is also feasible thanks to the `generate.exclude` key of the configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472634/8816585

Comment: If we exclude some parts of our app from ssr then google search console would not detect those excluded pages for SEO friendly, right? Google Search Console check every parts of our app if they are mobile responsive or not.

Comment: @Zia Google is actually able to parse client-side JS since a few years already. If you want to limit what google crawls, check [this page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/intro) especially the `no-index`one. And overall, you probably have some auth I guess, so that should not be a problem and your actual data will stay private.